For a particle moving in a central potential $V(r)$, how to calculate $[H, L_z]$?
For a particle moving in a central potential $V(r)$, how to calculate $[H, L_z]$? Answer is zero. but how to prove it.

There is no such thing as a conservative potential. There are conservative forces that are associated with potentials but no conservative potential.

okay ... it's central potential V(r)

Answer it please

Answer it please Homework-like questions that exhibit no effort and that don’t explain what you do and don’t understand shouldn’t be answered. Do you know what the commutator of two operators means? Do you know the canonical commutators between position and momentum operators? Can you express the Hamiltonian in terms of position and momentum? Where are you blocked in evaluating the commutator?

\begin{align}
[H,L_z]&=\bigg[({1\over 2m}{p^2}+V(r)),L_z\bigg]\\
       &={1\over 2m}\bigg[(p_x^2+p_y^2+p_z^2),L_z\bigg]+\bigg[V(r),L_z\bigg]\\
       &={1\over 2m}p_x\bigg[p_x,L_z\bigg]+{1\over 2m}\bigg[p_x,L_z\bigg]p_x+{1\over 2m}p_y\bigg[p_y,L_z\bigg]+{1\over 2m}\bigg[p_y,L_z\bigg]p_y+{1\over 2m}p_z\bigg[p_z,L_z\bigg]+{1\over 2m}\bigg[p_z,L_z\bigg]p_z+\bigg[V(r),L_z\bigg].\\
     \end{align}
Where we have used the properties of linearity of commutators along with the general formula:
$$[AB,C]=A[B,C]+[A,C]B.$$
At this point, for the sake of brevity, let us only work with the terms concerning $x$, since handling the rest will be similar. So we have that:
$$
\begin{align}
p_x[p_x,L_z]+[p_x,L_z]p_x&=p_x[p_x,(xp_y-yp_x)]+[p_x,(xp_y-yp_x)]p_x\\
&=p_x[p_x,xp_y]-p_x[p_x,yp_x]+[p_x,xp_y]p_x-[p_x,yp_x]p_x\\
&=-p_x[xp_y,p_x]+p_x[yp_x,p_x]-[xp_y,p_x]p_x+[yp_x,p_x]p_x\\
\end{align}$$
Again, one must employ the formula $[AB,C]=A[B,C]+[A,C]B$, and that is all there really is to working these kind of problems, keep employing linearity and the properties of commutators over and over again until each term involves a commutator which can be evaluated, in this case, in terms of the canonical commutation relations. At this point you are likely able to work the problem yourself being careful not to make a simple error in keeping track of all the indices and terms.

ans is zero. prove it

@Rex1947 Yes, the answer is zero because the Hamiltonian commutes with $L_z$. I have given you all the tools and direction you need to prove it. At least I did that much, the others simply closed your question. If you don't care enough about getting the answer not to take what I have given you and go with it, then oh well.

thanks dear ... got it.

@Rex1947 If you attempt working it and you get stuck somewhere, shoot me a line, and I will see if I can help. Good luck to you.

yup sure. but i just asked another question. but closed ? why

@Rex1947 You have to be very careful about how you ask questions here. You have ask about principles and concepts, and not about how to do this or that, or is this correct. The folks who do most of the closing are sometimes more active than at other times, and sometimes they do not work consistently; but I suppose they're only human.  You have to show exactly what you done and ask about what concepts you are not understanding. That is important so answers can be tailored to your needs. There are some other forums on the web that are more tolerant in these aspects.

A simple answer is that Hamiltonian of this case is invariant under rotation, therefore $[H, \mathbf{L}]=0$
